# KnockoutJS click binding returning a promise

Tags: knockout.js

When using KnockoutJS if the function that was called with a click handler returned a promise would it cause any problems?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you expand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: have you tried? It is very easy to test this yourself.

To answer directly: it depends on what you're thinking of (some more elaboration would've been nice).

If you happen to have a function that performs some logic, and returns a promise (for some reason totally unrelated to the click binding you're making) you can call it from your click handler, you could even use it as a click handler directly.

If however the logic behind the click handler depends on the asynchronous task and needs to wait for it to finish, you can't use said function as a click handler, because the returned promise will be ignored. You can still define a click handler that calls the function, and creates a callback on the returned promise.

Anything more specific needs a more elaborate question, ideally with a (pseudo)code example of the situation you're thinking of.

an example:

```
function asyncLogic() {
     var deferred = $.Deferred();
     // Perform async logic, then resolve
     setTimeout(function () {
         deferred.resolve();
     }, 100);
     return deferred.promise();
}

function handleClick(event) {
    // Disable the button, then perform the async logic, when its done re-enable the button
    $(event.target).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    asyncLogic().then(function () {
        $(event.target).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}

<form>
     <input type="submit" data-bind="click: handleClick" />
</form>
```